# Showing an equality with sequences and sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a,b$ be two real numbers and $(a_n) \subset \mathbb{Q}$ be a decreasing sequence of rationals such that $a_n \to a $. Also, take a strictly increasing sequence $(b_n) \subset \mathbb{Q} $ such that $b_n \to b $. Does it follow that

$$ \bigcup_{n \geq 1} (a_n, b_n] = (a,b) $$

???
$$ Attempt $$

If $x \notin \bigcup (a_n, b_n ]$, then for all $n$ wither $x \leq a_n$ or $x >b_n $. Passing to the limit, we obtain that $x \leq a $ or $x \geq b $ and so $x \notin (a,b)$. Hence, $(a,b) \subset \bigcup (a_n, b_n] $

Conversely, let $x \in \bigcup(a_n,b_n] $. We can find $n_0 $ so that $ a_{n_0} < x \leq b_{n_0} $. since $(a_n)$ is decreasing $a \leq a_{n_0} $ and since $(b_n) $ is increasing $b_{n_0} < b $ hence, $x \in (a,b)$

Is this a valid argument?

Comment: In the first line after "Attempt", you have an or statement that became an and statement after "Passing to the limit" - that's probably incorrect. I think this direction is more easily proved directly (rather than the contrapositive): if $x\in(a,b)$ then $x\in\bigcup (a_n,b_n]$ - you just have to show there exists $n_0$ such that $x\in(a_{n_0},b_{n_0}]$.

Comment: The second half is basically fine modulo typos: $(a_n)$ is decreasing, not increasing, and $a\le a_{n_0}$ rather than $a<a_{n_0}$.

Comment: but then $x$ would be in $[a,b)$ not in $(a,b)$ as we want.

Comment: No, because you already know that $a_{n_0}<x$ (as opposed to $\le x$), so $a\le a_{n_0}$ is all you need.